# Pass by value, no deep copy on assignment with std::vector?

Tags: c++, vector, set

Understanding `std::set.insert` & `std::vector` behavior.
Please consider the following scenario:

**A.h**

```
class A {
  uint id;
  vector<double> values;
  operator<(const A& argA) const;
}
```

**A.cpp**

```
A::A(uint argId, vector<double> argValues) {
    this->id = argId;
    this->values = argValues;
}

A::operator<(const A& argA) const {
    // it's guaranteed that there's always at least one element in the vector
    return this->values[0] < argA.values[0];
}
```

**B.cpp**

```
std::set<A> mySet;
for (uint i = 0; i < (uint) 10; i++)
{
  vector<double> tempVector(3);
  for (uint j = 0; j < (uint) 3; j++) {
    tempVector[j] = j;
  }

  myset.insert(A(i + 1, tempVector));
}
```

In my understanding, `tempElement` owns a deep copied vector (values), because the `vector` was passed by value in its constructor and assigned. Therefore looping over i shouldn't break the added elements to my set. BUT inserting `*tempElement` breaks - SIGSEV. In my logic this should work... Every help appreciated!

**EDIT:** the code crashes during the insertion process (second element); set invokes the LT-operator, tries to access the vector of the passed argument - but cannot. Before the creation of A where I pass the id and the vector I check if the passed vector contains the right elements.

Comment: Why do you allocate tempElement dynamically? You have a memory leak in your code in the manner it is written(tempElement does not get deleted). You can do all in one line like so: myset.insert(A(i+1, tempVector));

Comment: It gets deleted when I delete myset. It invokes the destructors of all contained elements.

Comment: @Eric: No, it doesn't.  The object that you put into your set is a copy of the object you dynamically allocated.  The dynamically allocated object itself is lost.

Comment: You're not showing us your real code.

Comment: @Eric, no the one that gets allocated on the heap with 'new' does not get deallocated when the set does - the set gets a copy.

Comment: @Eric - no it does not. You insert a copy of tempElement in the set not a pointer to it.

Comment: Please post a small compilable example (and there doesn't look to be a need for multiple files). As posted, `class A` can't be used with a `std::set` because there's no comparison capability for `A` objects (i.e., there's no `operator<()` for `A`). You should get a compile error long before you have a chance for a `SIGSEGV`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Agreed - there are lots of issues with this code, if you want help you need to share the real thing or at least make sure that your example compiles & exhibits the problem.

Comment: And even if the set stored a reference to the `new`d object, invoking the destructor does not `delete` the object. Using the `new` operator is a combination of allocating memory and calling the constructor. `delete` operator is a combination of calling the destructor and then deallocating the memory. Construction/destruction is orthogonal to allocation/deallocation. Therefore even though the set does destroy the object it holds, it never `delete`s those objects. But again, a set holds a copy of the object you pass, not a reference to it, so the set can't `delete` the object you `new` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

For a small vector it shouldn't matter, but if you have a large array and it will be expensive to keep copying it, your`A` should contain some kind of pointer that shallow-copies. There are several options:

1. `boost::shared_array<double>`
2. `boost::shared_ptr<vector<double> >`
3. `boost::shared_ptr<double>` but with array deleter passed in on construction.
4. Make A non-copyable and have a set of (shared) pointers to A with some comparison functor that compares what is in the pointers rather than the pointers themselves.

Note that with either `shared_array` or `shared_ptr` you won't be able to extract the size (number of elements) so you would have to store that separately.

Comment: `std::shared_ptr<>` is also available since C++11.

Comment: @WTP C++11 also supports move semantics, which (if the code is rewritten correctly) should eliminate all of the extra copies.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the problem is in this code. However I notice you have a vector tempVector but you assing the values to tempComponents instead. I can't see tempComponents declaration but my guess is it is of different size.

Comment: `tempComponents` has been removed from the question.  Apperently a copy-paste error.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no reason for inserting into myset here to cause a crash. The problem must lie elsewhere. Perhaps in A's copy ctor if you're not using the default one.

However your code is leaking memory. When you insert into the set `*tempElement` is copied into the set, and then the original that you allocated with `new` is no longer used but is never deleted. Instead you could just do `A tempElement(i+1,tempVector);` so that after the object is copied into the set it gets properly destroyed. Or perhaps better in this case you could just construct it as a temporary passed directly to insert: `myset.insert(A(i+1,tempVector))` in which case the object will be moved instead of copied, reducing the overhead. Or you could just construct the object in place to avoid even moving: `myset.emplace(i+1,tempVector);`

Also I'm assuming that by `tempComponents[j] = j;` you meant `tempVector[j] = j`. You could replace that loop with `std::iota(begin(tempVector),end(tempVector),0)`. **edit: or you could use the new initializer syntax** Furthermore, since the vector is the same everytime you could use just one outside the loop:

```
vector<double> tempVector(3) = {0.0,1.0,2.0}
std::set<A> mySet;
for (uint i = 0; i < (uint) 10; i++)
{
  myset.emplace(i+1,tempVector);
}
```

C++03 compilers won't support `emplace` or the new initializer syntax, and `iota` would be a compiler extension for them (it's from the original SGI STL, so some may have it). For those you would still use insert and use a for loop to initialize tempVector or use an array:

```
double tempVector_init[] = {0.0,1.0,2.0};
vector<double> tempVector(tempVector_init,tempVector_init+3);
std::set<A> mySet;
for (uint i = 0; i < (uint) 10; i++)
{
  myset.insert(A(i+1,tempVector));
}
```

Comment: Thank you @bames54, but I'm using an older version that doesn't support this syntax.

Comment: @Eric you can still do `insert(A(i+1,tempVector)` if `emplace` is not supported and you will at least get the benefit of move semantics as soon as it's available without further changes to the code. I'll add a version of my sample code for C++03 compilers.

Answer (score 0):

Working code with numerous changes - but I don't see the problem that you were describing.

```
#include <set>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

typedef unsigned int uint;

class A {
public:
  A(uint argId, vector<double> argValues) 
  {
    this->id = argId;
    this->values = argValues;
  }

  bool operator < ( A const& a ) const 
  { 
    return a.id < id;
  }

  uint id;
  vector<double> values;
};


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

  std::set<A> mySet;
  for (uint i = 0; i < (uint) 10; i++)
  {
    vector<double> tempVector(3);
    for (uint j = 0; j < (uint) 3; j++) {
      tempVector[j] = j;
    }

    std::unique_ptr<A> tempElement(new A(i + 1, tempVector));
    mySet.insert(*tempElement);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort, @Zac. I'm using another version that doesn't support std::unique_ptr syntax.